# Конфликт jQuery: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Консоль выдает такую ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at profile.php?id=1:122
```

Пробовал в пустом .php файле, там всё работает отлично, сделал вывод что какой-то внутренний скрипт мешает работе. `$.noConflict();` не помогло. Как решить эту проблему?

PHP файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/smiles/emojionearea.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

*Стили и прочие не-скриптовые записи опущены в `<head>`*.

Все подключенные модули отвечают *Response code: 200*.

Сам скрипт:

```
<div class="box-v5 panel">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() { //Та самая строчка, на которую ругается консоль
            $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
                pickerPosition: "left",
                tonesStyle: "bullet"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="panel-heading padding-0 bg-white border-none">
    <textarea id="emojionearea1">Default :smile:</textarea>
```

Comment: Где тут `php`? Вижу только `js` и `html`.

Comment: Если ругается именно на эту строку, то можно попробовать такой вариант: `$(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: вставьте в начало обработчика `ready` - `console.log($);`

Comment: Такая же ошибка.

Comment: @xYaroslavGTx а вы уверены тогда, что ошибка не на строке с `document.ready`?

Comment: @Regent После того как добавил $(document).ready(function() {  консоль стала показывать что ошибка в этой строке.

Comment: вставьте `console.log($);` перед `$(...`

Comment: @Igor (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)}

Comment: @xYaroslavGTx это совсем другое дело тогда. В таком случае: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: @Regent Благодарю, теперь всё работает, правда проявились последствия "Uncaught TypeError: editor.textcomplete is not a function" но как я понимаю это уже связанно не с этим кодом.

Comment: @xYaroslavGTx да, это уже что-то другое. Я оформлю свой комментарий как ответ тогда.

Comment: @Regent Угу, еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дабы избежать конфликта с `$`, можно воспользоваться таким вариантом:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //использование jQuery как $
}
```

Объект `jQuery` передаётся в функцию, вызываемую при `document.ready`, в качестве первого параметра. Так как параметру можно задать любое имя, то для этого вполне подойдёт `$`. А так как это локальная переменная (параметр), то при использовании `$` внутри функции браться будет она, а не глобальная переменная `$` (которая где-то в коде была заменена с `jQuery` на что-то другое).

---

Аналогично для "короткого" варианта `document.ready`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //использование jQuery как $
});
```

---

При использовании вне `document.ready`:

```
(function($) {
    //использование jQuery как $
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});
```